# Mysql access denied error

Tags: database, error, mysql

I have a common problem but the usual solutions are not working so apologies for what on first appearance may seem like a previously asked question.

I have the following error when trying to view my site on my local

```
    Access denied for user 'sitename'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The credentials being used wrong but I don't know where they are coming from.
I have checked app/etc/local.xml and it has all correct credentials. 
I have removed all other xml files from the directory (except config.xml).
I have deleted the contents of the var folder (numerous times)

I have other magento sites working on my local so my server settings should be fine. I'm really stumped on this and don't know what next step I should take. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would go to the connect method in DB adapter and right before the call to the connection method, place something like: '$e = new Exception(); Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString(), null, 'logname', true);' getting trace like this is more compact. Then in that trace see for any odd code paths. Also log actual credentials that are passed to PDO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the other answers were a great way to narrow down all of the possibilities as to what the issue could have been. For this I felt each of them deserved an up vote. They did not directly solve my problem so I felt I should give an answer myself as a courtesy and also because a lot of people use wordpress with magento.

This particular site uses wordpress as a module. This module contains db credentials as well as the usual magento app/etc/local.xml. I was not aware that this module is rendered pretty much all over the site and is relevant to the database. As a result it made it impossible to view the site without changing the details in here too.

Answer (score 8):

You need to make the user `sitename@localhost` able to access the database and tables in question. Use the following SQL as a root or superuser on the MySQL instance to grant the privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON magento_local.* TO 'sitename'@'localhost';
```

For more information on Grants in MYSQL see the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came across this option earlier but i didn't think it would work. Because user:'sitename' and pass:'yes' are not the correct/specified db credentials I assumed this does not really solve the issue of wrong details being used or can it somehow find the details in app/etc/local.xml after being able to connect to the db once with the wrong details

Comment: There's a difference between accessing mysql directly and over 'localhost' which is via network. You need to grant explicitly on the localhost location.

Comment: remember and run:`flush privileges`after your grant command

Answer (score 5):

In case local.xml is being overridden search your site for files containing something like `<username>sitename</username>`.  For this sort of work I prefer [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/):

```
ack --xml "<username>.*sitename.*</username>" app/
```

...or even just:

```
ack sitename app/
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to clear cache, maybe you are using 3rd party caching layers, disable them. Last option is rename app/etc/local.xml and open website, Magento should run installation process, during installation provide old encryption key from local.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, following solved this for me:

1. Download the original version of Magento
2. backup your app/etc (ex.: app/_etc)
3. Upload the original app/etc from the original Magento folder
4. Go to your site and do the Magento installation process, I used my original database name, database settings (user/pw) and encryption key.
5. Upload your app/etc/modules into the new ETC folder
6. After installation I could login and clear cache. The website was working again like before.